# Compare value of cells in a column to value of cells in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns of data on the same worksheet.

I want to compare all the values in column B to the last value in column A. If they are the same, call a certain function. Then move to the next value in column A, and compare to all values in B again, etc.

```
Sub FindSamples()
Dim first As String
Dim second As String
Dim j As Long
Dim i As Long

Dim lastRowNumber As Long
Dim lastRowNumberDDH As Long

With Sheets("Shape Point Info")

    lastRowNumber = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowNumberDDH = .Cells(Rows.Count, 20).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastRowNumberDDH To 0 Step -1
        For j = lastRowNumber To 0 Step -1
            second = Cells(j, 4).Value
            first = Cells(i, 20).Value
            If first = second Then
                'Call something
                Worksheets("Shape Point Info").Range("J14").Value = "Yes"
            Else:
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End With
End Sub
```

My errors are on lines 17 and 18 of my code:

```
second = Cells(j, 4).Value
first = Cells(i, 20).Value
```

I get

> "Run time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Try adding a `.` in front of `Cells`

Comment: There is no row 0 change ```For i = lastRowNumberDDH To 0 Step -1
       For j = lastRowNumber To 0 Step -1 ``` to 1

Comment: Thank you Warcupine! Ugh I can't believe I did that. That fixed it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Cells, Rows, Columns, and almost all collections and items in VBA are **1-indexed**. Therefore you cannot access Rows(0), and this is the issue with your code. You have to amend your `For` lines as such:

```vb
For i = lastRowNumberDDH To 1 Step -1
   For j = lastRowNumber 1 Step -1
```